# Does observer design pattern method violate SRP when do 2 things: setting and notifying

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I just read this sample code from the observer design pattern from [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm). However, could anyone please explain whether the **`setState` method** (not asking about the `Subject` class) is doing 2 things (setting the `state` and notifying the `observers`)?

If Yes, then does the method `setState` violate the single responsibility principle (SRP)?

If No, then how we could understand the SRP correctly? Thank you in advance.

*I also follow [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281853/does-the-observer-pattern-violate-single-responsibiliy-principle) but could not find a proper answer.*

```
public class Subject {
   private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
   private int state;

   public void setState(int state) {
     this.state = state;
     notifyAllObservers();
   }

   public void notifyAllObservers(){
     for (Observer observer : observers) {
        observer.update();
     }
   }

   // [...omitted other unrelated methods...]
}
```

Comment: Well, changing the state in the subject is by definition should be reacted by observers. So, it's not broken the SRP -- the setState does one thing -- notifies observers that reflects any state change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Observer pattern violate single responsibiliy principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281853/does-the-observer-pattern-violate-single-responsibiliy-principle)

Comment: Note the collection of observers really should be a Set, else you run the risk of sending duplicate notifications to the same observer.

Comment: @jaco0646  thanks for your reply, but I could not find the proper answer according to the link. Still expecting someone can have a better one.

Comment: SRP shouldn't be interpreted as an assurance that a class, module, etc. "does one thing". It actually means "one reason to change" and those reasons are actors. Meaning, change in a class, ..., should impact a single actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is explicitly about whether the method 'setState' does 2 things. The answer is no.

To quote 'Clean Code' p.36:

> If a function does only those steps that are one level below the stated name of the function, then the function is doing one thing. After all, the reason we write functions is to decompose a larger concept (in other words, the name of the function) into a set of steps at the next level of abstraction. ... So, another way to know that a function is doing more than 'one thing' is if you can extract another function from it with a name that is not merely a restatement of its implementation.

The difficulty is that the name 'setState(int state)' suggests that the function sets the state (with this.state = state;) and then calls another function, doing 2 things.

```
public void setState(int state) {
 this.state = state;
 notifyAllObservers();
```

}

However, if we rename the function to processChange() it becomes clear that the function consists of doing 1 thing (processing the change) in 2 steps (1. setting the state and 2. notifying the observers, the 'set of steps at the next level of abstraction' in the above quote).

```
public void processChange(int state) {
 this.state = state;
 notifyAllObservers();
```

}

Comment: `processChange()` is quite a vague name. We could put 100 lines of code in that method and claim that every line is processing a change.

Comment: @jaco0646 Indeed we could: 'put 100 lines of code in that method and claim that every line is processing a change', but the claim is that the lines of code in the method are a set of steps at the next level of abstraction. Claiming they are all 'processing a change' puts them at the same level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to quote Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob) on this one :

> **SRP: The Single Responsibility Principle**
>   There should never be more than one reason for a class to change.

([ref.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150202200348/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf))

So a class *can* be doing more than one thing, as long as it has only one reason to change.

I'd say you're fine.

Comment: That's much easier to quote than to define. And a class doing more than one thing will likely lead you to have more than one reason to change. it's likely a class that does *one* thing will have more than one reason to change. And even still, "One Reason to Change" is in itself confusing which is why Uncle Bob admits many misunderstand it and misapply it with a primary example of "does one thing".

Answer (score 1):

The example from the given [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) is not really good and the naming `setState()` causes confusion as it does notifying (not related to the setting).

Changing the name to e.g. `processStateChanged()`would help in this case.